# zlib_decode(): data error using composer in the doctrine2 tutorial

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

UPDATE:
I posted this issue to the bug tracker a while ago as suggested in comments, and now I ran a clean installation of the new version of composer (Composer version 7131607ad1d251c790ce566119d647e008972aa5 2014-05-27 14:26:24) and the issue is fixed.

ORIGINAL POST:
I'm trying to learn how to use doctrine2 using their tutorial at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

but for some reason I get this error when trying to run `composer install`:

```
  [ErrorException]           
  zlib_decode(): data error
```

Here is the contents of composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

EDIT: PHP Version 5.5.9.

EDIT: output of `composer install -vvv`:

```
Reading ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-active$1874cad4a77f2dbd91c33e813330434e6c38cd940846c58a610595dac158d161.json
Writing C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-active.json into cache
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-archived$02a49245f4912f279bea7cd3a287cb32b6ab02623037965e5f9665bf27fe3ec9.json
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-archived$02a49245f4912f279bea7cd3a287cb32b6ab02623037965e5f9665bf27fe3ec9.json
Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-archived$02a49245f4912f279bea7cd3a287cb32b6ab02623037965e5f9665bf27fe3ec9.json
  [ErrorException]
  zlib_decode(): data error
Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:217
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a
 zlib_decode() at phar://C:/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem
.php:217
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->get() at phar://C:/composer/composer/src/Compos
er/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:82
 Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getContents() at phar://C:/composer/composer/sr
c/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:612
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->fetchFile() at phar://C:/composer/compo
ser/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:519
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->loadProviderListings() at phar://C:/com
poser/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:271
 Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->whatProvides() at phar://C:/composer/co
mposer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:254
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->computeWhatProvides() at phar://C:/composer/c
omposer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:243
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->whatProvides() at phar://C:/composer/composer
/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:149
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->setupInstalledMap() at phar://C:/composer/c
omposer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:163
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve() at phar://C:/composer/composer/src/
Composer/Installer.php:467
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar://C:/composer/composer/src/Composer/Ins
taller.php:215
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/composer/composer/src/Composer/Command/I
nstallCommand.php:122
 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar://C:/composer/composer/vendo
r/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:241
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/composer/composer
/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:892
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/composer/com
poser/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/composer/composer/s
rc/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/composer/composer/vendor/sym
fony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/composer/composer/src
/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/composer/composer/bin/composer
:43
 require() at C:\composer\composer:15
install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p
lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver
bose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Comment: Check if you have zlib enabled with `php -m`. zlib provides zlib_decode and this extension should be active under your PHP installation.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexandruG. It's showing when running php -m.

Comment: Maybe a network issue then, or you hit github API limitations ?

Comment: I don't think I hit any github limitation, I'm only using it for practice. How can I check for a network issue?

Comment: Run `composer install -vvv` and update your initial question with the output of that command.

Comment: @AlexandruG. output attached.

Comment: Your composer.json works OK on my end (PHP 5.5.8), so this must be a problem with your environment. What PHP version are you using and you are behind a proxy ?

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.9 and I don't know of any proxy. Unless my ISP voluntarily put my behind one. Is that likely? Should I call them and ask?
Another thing, I tried on Windows 8 and on Ubuntu 14.04 on a VM.
@AlexandruG.

Comment: Run `composer diagnose` and if everything shows OK, you should post this issue on [composer's issue tracker](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues) from github, where you could get more help from core developers.

Comment: My composer was not installed correctly, no it is. But this error still shows. I guess I'll post it to the issue tracker. Thanks, @AlexandruG.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I couldn't help you more. When you solve the problem you could post the solution here as an answer.

Comment: @AlexandruG. thanks a lot, just wanted to tell you that I currently installed a new version and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

During the last day I've spend a lot of time trying to deal with `zlib_decode(): data error` problem and it definitely is not related to what exact package you are trying to install. It has to do something with proxy and/or bad internet connection. Disabling antivirus did not help my case as I'm not using antivirus on my Mac. These are the things that did help in the end.

**1. Force HTTPS for package retrieval by adding this to your `composer.json`.**

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    {"packagist": false}
  ],
  "require": { /* your packages as usual */ }
}
```

**2. If you still experience the problem, try to run `composer diag`. In my case few of the messages there were:**

```
Checking pubkeys: FAIL
Missing pubkey for tags verification
Missing pubkey for dev verification
Run composer self-update --update-keys to set them up
```

After doing `composer self-update --update-keys` and following the instructions - on the next attempt, all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Avast antivirus. After disabling  everything updated without problems.

Answer (score -1):

Just install unzip on your machine, if you are using debian/ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

That works for me!